# Xamarin - Breakpoints crash emulator when connecting to iOS machine

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am running Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.2 on a Windows 10 PC, and I am using a Mac Desktop machine to run the iOS compilation and emulation side of my Xamarin Forms project.

Whenever I run my Xamarin Forms project on iOS mode, and have breakpoints in my code, I receive this error message:

`Unable to connect to Mac Server with Address='xxx.xxx.xx.xxx' and User='Me'. An active connection is required to perform the build`

If I remove breakpoints, boot any iOS emulator and then add a breakpoint while the program is running I get this error:

``` EXCEPTION: Mono.Debugging.Soft.DisconnectedException: The connection with the debugger has been lost. The target application may have exited. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly ``Mono.Posix, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified at Mono.Debugging.Soft.SoftDebuggerSession.ResolveSymbolicLink(String path) ```

Comment: the error  occurs on simulator or real device?

Comment: On all of the iOS simulators

Comment: Did you try to delete all the breakpoints and set again?

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56787 refer to here